# React gives an error message "cannot be used as a JSX component"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, dependencies, yarnpkg

After installing the dependencies, errors appeared throughout the project like Component cannot be used as a JSX component.
Error Example

[image]

The error is kind of strange, i ran the project with exactly the same dependency and everything started fine, but here is an error that i can't figure out how to solve.

package.json file

````
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.21.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.21.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.10",
        "@svgr/cli": "5.5.0",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
        "@types/circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.0.5",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
        "@types/webpack": "^5.28.0",
        "@types/webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.1",
        "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
        "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
        "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
        "eslint": "^8.0.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^34.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
        "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "json-server": "^0.17.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "svgo": "2.7.0",
        "ts-morph": "16.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
        "typescript": "*",
        "webpack": "^5.69.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
        "@splinetool/react-spline": "^2.2.6",
        "@splinetool/runtime": "^0.9.374",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
        "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1"
    },```
Tried:
Reinstall dependencies
Update @types/react
The only +- thing that helped was removing the wrapper React.memo
````

Comment: How is `<Header>` or `<MainLayout>` declared? Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)